# Do paragon levels affect the difficulty of enemies?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3, (2.0)  enemies now level with you, but does that include Paragon levels? are enemies getting more difficult with each Paragon level I gain? or do they only get more difficult by increasing the difficulty level after the normal level cap (60/70)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enemies increase in difficulty only based on your main level (1-70) and then the difficulty you choose to play on (Normal - Torment 10, or Greater Rift level, or Easy - Master V on Consoles). The paragon levels you gain after hitting level 70 do not increase the power of monsters (they stay at the same difficulty as when you were level 70 without any paragon levels).

Comment: So you have a source to this theory?

Comment: @Bora It may be hard to find a Blue post directly stating that Paragon levels do not increase difficulty, because everyone knows they don't, and not many people actually ask. Paragon levels are intended to be an endless miniscule rewards to give grindings players something guaranteed for their effort. It would be strange to punish players my making game ever harder.

Comment: Well, I share the same opinion, and what the heuristic shows, it has no effect. Been playing T2 for a long time and no tangible increase in difficulty. But I believe, science is not just about our inclinations :)

Comment: I have spent a bit of time looking but couldn't find anything that specifically says that paragon levels do not increase monster difficulty

Comment: I can confirm that enemies dont scale to my witch hunter with capped paragon

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of threads to this topic in the official forums.

- [Paragon Level and Group Difficulty](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12428733228)
- [Do Paragon levels affect difficulty?](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12471017533)
- [Dynamic Difficulty and Paragon 2.0](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9863156403)

Even if none of these has a blue answer, they all say the same: Game difficulty is only determined by character level and not affected by paragon level.

Also in my opinion it would not make much sense to implement it different. Imagine you are paragon 400 and create a level 1 character: Should be game really be 400 times harder than for a paragon 1 account?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure Paragon leveling doesn't scale the mosters. Playing on Torment VI with my Paragon around 100, I usually encountered the blues at some 300+M of hp - but now, as I am nearing Paragon Level 300, the blues are ALWAYS around 500M. The yellows used to be at some 600M-700M - now they are at 1B+.